# Issue sending data Heroku from swift application

Tags: swift, authentication, heroku, postman

I am trying to send create user data from my swift application to heroku sever using mongolab. I can send data from postman and it is showing on mogolab but when I sending through swift application it is giving me following error

> 2019-07-02 22:43:49.473763-0700 Smack[2903:99473] [MC] System group
>   container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
>   /Users/amansingh/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/53EA3DDB-EA13-45F9-A9C4-6EB6ABF911A1/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   2019-07-02 22:43:49.474887-0700 Smack[2903:99473] [MC] Reading from
>   private effective user settings. 2019-07-02 22:44:12.737834-0700
>   Smack[2903:99604] [AutoFill] Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords
>   for app bundleID: com.learning.0363.Smack due to error: iCloud
>   Keychain is disabled

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON


class AuthService {
    static let instance = AuthService()

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var isLoggedIn : Bool {
        get {
            return defaults.bool(forKey: LOGGED_IN_KEY)
        }
        set {
            defaults.set(newValue, forKey: LOGGED_IN_KEY)
        }
    }

    var authToken : String {
        get {
            return defaults.value(forKey: TOKEN_KEY) as! String
        }
        set {
            defaults.set(newValue, forKey: TOKEN_KEY)
        }
    }

    var userEmail: String {
        get {
            return defaults.value(forKey: USER_EMAIL) as! String
        }
        set {
            defaults.set(newValue, forKey: USER_EMAIL)
        }
    }

    func registerUser(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping CompletionHandler){

        let lowerCaseEmail = email.lowercased()

        let body: [String: Any] = [
            "email": lowerCaseEmail,
            "password": password

        ]
        Alamofire.request(URL_REGISTER, method: .post, parameters: body, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: HEADER).responseString { (response) in
            if response.result.error == nil {
                completion(true)
            }else{
                completion(false)
                debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
            }
        }
    }
    func loginUser(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping CompletionHandler){
        let lowerCaseEmail = email.lowercased()

        let body: [String: Any] = [
            "email": lowerCaseEmail,
            "password": password

        ]

        Alamofire.request(URL_LOGIN, method: .post, parameters: body, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: HEADER).responseString { (response) in
            if response.result.error == nil {
//                if let json =  response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, Any>{
//                    if let email = json["user"] as? String {
//                        self.userEmail = email
//                    }
//                    if let token = json["token"] as? String {
//                        self.authToken = token
//                    }
//                }
                //USING SWIFTY JSON
                guard let data = response.data else {
                    return
                }
                do {
                    let json = try JSON(data: data)
                    self.userEmail = json["user"].stringValue
                    self.authToken = json["token"].stringValue
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }


                self.isLoggedIn = true
                completion(true)
            }else{
                completion(false)
                debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
            }
        }


    }




}
```

It shows logged in but when i checked my data in data base its not there

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "my data in data base its not there", however, regarding the error, the message is somehow explicit :

> [AutoFill] Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: com.learning.0363.Smack due to error: iCloud Keychain is disabled

The application tries to automatically fill some credential textfields at some point, but you iCloud keychain is disable, preventing the system to retrieve your login / password infos from your device.

---

Try to enable it from settings like so :

- Choose Settings > [your name]
- Tap Keychain and slide to turn it on.
- Enter your Apple ID, and follow the instructions.

[image]

---

Just to think ahead, you may encounter a similar error if you had the **Autofill** disable on your device as well.

Here is a pretty quick tutorial that shows how to set up all these :

https://robopress.robotsandpencils.com/strong-passwords-in-ios-12-8ec819b3b99